# I have verbally accepted an offer but I want to continue with other applications. Should I rescind my acceptance of the offer?

Tags: job-search

Due to my financial situation, I had to accept an offer from company A. I do not like the offer, and the company probably knows the offer they made was anything but gracious: contractor job, instead of a permanent role, and low pay. I still thought it was an okay opportunity, because they would probably increase my hourly rate in a few months, and they were nice, and the projects I would be working on look okay. And it is still an offer when I am in financial trouble.

However, since it is not a permanent role, it is too risky for me to withdraw my applications. Rescinding the offer is also risky because of my financial situation.

I have an interview scheduled for next week, and other interviews are just starting to roll in.

I could tell company B that I already accepted an offer, but then it would be impossible to explain them why, if I do not like the offer that much (without telling the truth, which would then reflect badly on me).

Not sure what I should do. I obviously made a mistake accepting the low pay, I did not negotiate. Rescinding the offer feels least bad, even if it is risky.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate...  Breaking a verbal acceptance is rude, since you're disrupting the company's planning process, but can be done with appropriate apology. You aren't actually hired until the commitment is on paper with salary and start date and so on, and the usual advice is to continue job hunting until that time.

Comment: Embrace the contractor aspect of this "job." A contractor can be fired at any time and can quit at any time. That includes quitting after working one hour. That also means that you can tell other companies that you are working but looking for better conditions.

Comment: @DavidR "A contractor can be fired at any time and can quit at any time." doesn't that heavily depend on the actual contract?

Comment: "Not sure what I should do. I obviously made a mistake accepting the low pay" I don't understand why do you think that, you have clearly financial pressures, and only an interview - not a competing offer.

Comment: @AidaPaul You are right, the mistake I made was that I accepted it right away without negotiating.

Comment: Location is needed. The US and Germany have very different labor laws for example. The US is "at will" which means you can quit 5 minutes into Day 1 and face no legal ramifications.

Answer (score 7):

No, don't rescind anything. There is no reason to take risks like that. Just carry on and keep searching. You need to look after yourself first and many people take jobs out of necessity and leave them early.

There's not much difference between this and the normal procedure of leaving a job for a better situation even if you've worked there for years.

Answer (score 4):

There are only two time you rescind an offer.

1. You cannot possibly do the job.
2. You just accepted a second job offer that would conflict with the first offer.

Any other scenarios equate to telling the world, "no thanks, I'd rather be unemployed"; because, that's what you will be, unemployed.

Remember the old saying

> A bird in the hand is better than two in the bush.

But in your scenario it's even worse.  You have a bird in the hand, but you are thinking of letting it go for possibly no birds in the bush.

Answer (score 2):

Until you have signed the contract, it is not final or binding.  The company is still free to hire someone else instead. And they will have no qualms doing so.  You need to look out for yourself first.  Just continue with Company B.  You don't need to tell them because you havent signed a contract yet.  You are not yet employed.

If you do get to the stage of signing the contract, and if you havent got any other offers, then sign it, noting the "notice of termination clause".  Then you need to tell future companies that you have a job and what notice you have to give.  Or if the term for notice is too long, then see if you can negotiate a shorter term before signing it.

Comment: in some jurisdictions, verbal commitments are binding, even if hard to enforce

Comment: "*There are only two time you rescind an offer.*" -- I think you mean "rescind an acceptance of an offer". (An employer could rescind an offer.)

Answer (score 2):

### Keep looking

It is usually poor form to go back on verbally accepting an offer, but since you have been upfront about wanting a permanent position it should come as no surprise. Furthermore, position as contractor is based on fluidity: They can offer you no work, and you can say no to it.

Until everything is signed, it is not agreed. (But it would be poor form to try to negotiate again, based on some second offer)

A mild apology and explanation that you have been offered a permanent position elsewhere is sufficient and professional should you get an offer and choose sign somewhere else.